# bootstrap feedback spinner when page loading by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

When I used to use JQuery mobile and I loaded a page the screen would darken and there would be an ajax spinner denoting something was happening.

How can I replicate this in Bootsrap as some of my pages take a second or 2 to load and the "just sitting there" approach isn't working for me?

Is it just as easy as hooking into $routeChangeStart and $routeChangeSuccess? does this last one fire AFTER the Ajax load?

Does anyone have a simple example?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this would be to use the jQuery `.load` function:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#loading").hide();
});
```

The `load` event is sent when the page is fully loaded.

Alternatively, you could use the `ajaxComplete` function:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, request) {
    $("#loading").hide();
});
```

Whenever an Ajax request completes, jQuery triggers the `ajaxComplete` event. Any and all handlers that have been registered with the `.ajaxComplete()` method are executed at this time.